# How to undo the most recent comment on git

Tags: github

While using git hub I wanted to delete/undo a comment that I had recently posted. But I was unable to do it. So I want to know how to undo the recent comment in git.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the several and easiest way to do it.

1. First of all lets check commit history.

```
git log --oneline
```

2. Now in the output you will see a list of commits. Something like shown below.

```
241b8e7 (HEAD -> papers) Added paper-logic according to new requirements
8ae8f7d paper backend fixed
3c9a3ce toggle sidebar change added
af1af34 link to style tag added
```

3. Now as per your question you want to undo previous commit i.e you want your project to be at 2nd last commit.

   So "code"(left of commit statement- "paper backend fixed" ) for 2nd last commit from the above example is `8ae8f7d`. Copy this code.
4. To go to that commit enter the following in terminal.
   `git reset --hard <code>`

What this will do is forcefully change all your project to the stage as it was on mentioned  commit. 
**Note that it is irreversible i.e once you have gone to previous commit you cannot come to commits above it**

Answer (score 0):

You need to undo the commit as well.

Undo Last Git Commit with reset

```
$ git reset --soft HEAD~1
```

If you are not familiar with this notation, “HEAD~1”
“HEAD~1” means that you want to reset the HEAD (the last commit) to one commit before in the log history.

You can use this as well

```
$ git reset --hard <commit sha1 | reference>
$ git push --force
```

to check the  commit hash and reference you can use

```
$ git log --oneline
```

or

```
$ git log
```

Undo Last Git Commit with revert

```
$ git log
$ git revert <commit sha1 | reference>
$ git push --force
```

You might want to check these as well
[How do I undo the most recent local commits in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-do-i-undo-the-most-recent-local-commits-in-git)